# Insert record with Date into list via JSOM, problem with UK Format

Tags: sharepoint-addin, date-time, app, client-object-model

I have found that when inserting a record which contains a Date using JSOM the `update();` will not work if you specify the format of the date to be UK date (28/05/2014).

The code does not error, it simply won't insert the data. If I change the format of the date to US (05/28/2014) it works but I want to use the UK method, especially when I'm using a data picker etc.

I have tried setting the regional settings to English (UK) within the site settings but this makes no difference.

To add some more detail...my HTML code is

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="GEDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date:</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="GEDate" name="GEDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Date"  />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and i use the following in my app.js

```
$('#GEDate').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

where i really want to use

```
$('#GEDate').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Any kind of manipulation on the value and SharePoint/JavaScript is saving that its invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible, have you tried setting the value to a JS date object instead of string? The alternative ofcourse is to write a function which fixes date string by swapping the day and month...

```
var arr = date.split('/');
var newDate = arr[1] + "/" + arr[0] + "/" + arr[2];
```

Comment: I had thought of this as I am using a bootstrap date picker which means the input object is text rather than date. Because of this the JS does not see it as a date object. So yes i guess i could try the above... I'm also considering changing the date field to a text field!!

Comment: To get the date object you can try this: $('#GEDate').val()
or
$('#GEDate').data('date')

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help or be overkill, Have you considered using the momentjs library?

Answer (score 0):

Today i have faced the same issue and i have resolve this, I have done the following things

1. Changed the regional Settings to India Zone **(UTC+5:30)** and Locale to **United Kingdom** (refer screen shot).
2. While saving using JSOM i have used **dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy"**

[image]